# Issue with SELECT MAX(DATE) GROUP BY WHERE SPECIFIC DATE

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, group-by, max

its my first question here thanks in advance for the help.
I have two tables **workers** and **rotation** where stores data from attendance, substitution etc. each worker have a record of what was the status that day(normal attendance,temp promotion for substitution or unjustified absence)  I want to know what was the last status of a worker's group without including today (knowing that may or may not has records today)I try this:

```
SELECT a.id_worker,MAX(b.datetime_event) 
FROM workers a INNER JOIN rotation b ON a.id_worker=b.id_worker
WHERE b.status_confirm=1
GROUP BY a.id_worker
HAVING MAX(b.datetime_event) < DATEADD(dd,DATEDIFF(dd,0,GETDATE()),0) --Today '00:00'
```

when I erase the HAVING clause works but just if doesnt exist a record today of course.

Im using SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Having` statements are to apply rules to items after they're in groups; you want to apply the filter before the items are grouped.  i.e. What you have above would return all groups for which the last date isn't today (a subset of the groups); what's below will return all groups with the last date prior to today (only a subset of the groups if the only entries for a group are from today or later).

```
SELECT a.id_worker,MAX(b.datetime_event) 
FROM workers a INNER JOIN rotation b ON a.id_worker=b.id_worker
WHERE b.status_confirm=1
and b.datetime_event < cast(cast(GETDATE() as date) as datetime) --Today '00:00'
GROUP BY a.id_worker
```

Comment: Ok thank for the replay was so fast, I misunderstand the group by and i was so bury in myself looking the wrong part on the inner join or group by. Many thanks man!